# In flow network Increase weight of edges with constraints to make all path weights equal

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a flow network with one source and one sink. There are no cycles in the flow network. I need to make weight of all the paths (from source to sink same) equal by increasing weight of edges. Constraint is that in a path weight of no more than 1 edge can be increased and weight of the path should be minimum.

Weight of path = sum of weight of all the edge along the path

See below example for explanation-

```
source - 1
sink - 6

Edges - 
1->2 8
1->5 12
1->4 7
2->4 2
2->3 4
3->6 6
4->6 8
5->6 10

Routes are - 
1->2->3->6 weight - 18
1->2->4->6 weight - 18
1->4->6 weight - 15
1->5->6 weight - 22

If i add weight like this

Add 4 to 3->6 
Add 4 to 2->4
Add 7 to 1->4


Total cost of all the routes become 22 which is minimum possible.
```

Comment: I think this is solvable with binary search+max flow. I'll think about the details and maybe post them later if no one else does.

Comment: @IVlad Can you please tell me the approach on how to do it using search+max flow?